# Detecting browser in ASP.NET using RegEx

Tags: regex

I am trying to detect the browser in my C# code by comparing the UserAgent string with some regular expressions.

By the way, in case you are wondering, the reason why I use this approach instead of simply using ASP.NET's HttpBrowserCapabilities object is because I have received a list of more than 200 regex that correspond to 200 browsers and their OS and I can get more detailed information.

Here's a sample:

```
var sampleUserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)";
var ieRegEx = "/^Mozilla\/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE ([0-9\.]+); Windows/si";
var success = Regex.Match(sampleUserAgent, regEx.RegularExpression, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

In this example I am expecting the regex match to be successful but for some reason, the match returns false. I am guessing that the regex is not quite right.

I didn't write the regex and I am not very familiar with the RegEx syntax so can anybody help me figure out what is wrong with the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like this in C#:

```
string sampleUserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0)";
string ieRegEx = @"^Mozilla/4.0 \(compatible; MSIE ([0-9\.]+); Windows .*\)$";
bool success = Regex.Match(sampleUserAgent, ieRegEx, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success;
```

Note I prefer using correct type identifiers rather than var for simple types.

Also, I personally would just stick to using Browser Caps as it would be much less hassle, especially if you aren't good with reg-ex.

Comment: Indeed the regex you suggested is successful. You have removed the "/" at the beggining, you have replaced "\/" with "/" and replaced "/si" at the end with ".*\)$" (what does that mean by the way?).

I try applying these changes to the 200 or so regex strings and see if that solves the problem for not only the IE regex but also all the others.

Comment: ^ anchors to start of line and / slashes don't need to be escaped (the \ character is an escape character). The $ matches end of line. The *. matches any sequence of characters. See http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Comment: thank you for the link to cheatsheet. Very informative! One last question: do have any idea what "\si" in the original regex means? I don't see any mention of it in the cheatsheet. I understand that you replaced it with ".*$" in order to match any number of characters un the end of string but I don't understand the intent of author of the original regex.

Comment: They are known as pattern or mode modifiers. The \s means "single line" so that even if the line breaks it still matches and \i means case-insensitive. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs.aspx http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html Normally in .net it is easier to use RegexOptions for this, rather than "inline" modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

I know this does not directly answer the question, but I think you are introducing more problems by using regex for this problem.  I would stick with   HttpBrowserCapabilities instead unless you have a real need do detect more detailed information.

Comment: I agree that it seems to make things more complicated but the reason I am really interested is because I found this web site: http://user-agent-string.info/

It has regex string for all known browsers and also all known Operating systems. It's very detailed.

Comment: As it goes I would treat BrowserCaps with extreme caution myself, but then I wouldn't trust user-agent either

Comment: @oren the errors, I believe, are due to the fact that the code and regex provided on the web site I mentioned are for PHP and I am trying to convert to C#. I am wondering if the regex "syntax" is slightly different in PHP versus .NET?

Comment: Yes.  They have different flavors of regex.  Regular Expressions Cookbook has a nice intro on this - http://www.amazon.com/Regular-Expressions-Cookbook-Jan-Goyvaerts/dp/0596520689/ref=cm_cr_pr_product_top

Answer (score 0):

I found this regex from [here](http://www.texsoft.it/index.php?c=software&m=sw.php.useragent&l=it)

> ^([^/[:space:]]*)(/([^[:space:]]*))?([[:space:]]*[[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]])?
>   [[:space:]]*(\((([^()]|(\([^()]*\)))*)\))?[[:space:]]*

which is supposed to match all useragents.  They also have a list for more specific useragents.